# solr query not returning any results

Tags: solr, lucene

New to Solr
I have uploaded a couple of documents.
I can see then using a get:
http://domain:8983/solr/core1/get?id=2

> ```
> {   "doc":   {
> "id":"2",
> "cus_name_s":"Paul Brown2",
> "cus_email_t":["paul.brown@test.net"],
> "com_id_i":201,
> "com_name_s":"com1",
> "url_s":"/integration/",
> "_version_":1506032461063127040}}
> ```

but when I issue this query:
http://domain:8983/solr/core1/query?q=cus_email_t:paul&fl=id

I get

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "fl":"id",
      "q":"cus_email_t:paul"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Comment: Please add snippets of your schema !

Comment: Apologies: where do I get the schema from? I thought I could just create the above document on the fly once I had built a core?

Comment: Usually you have a file `schema.xml` in a directory `conf`. In that file, you will probably have an element `<field name="cus_email_t" type="..." .../>`. The value of the `type` attribute is relevant for your question.

Comment: [root@ip-172-31-25-*** solr]# find / -name "schema.xml"
/solr/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf/schema.xml
/solr/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/schema.                                                                            xml
/solr/solr-5.2.1/example/example-DIH/solr/mail/conf/schema.xml
/solr/solr-5.2.1/example/example-DIH/solr/db/conf/schema.xml
/solr/solr-5.2.1/example/example-DIH/solr/rss/conf/schema.xml
/solr/solr-5.2.1/example/example-DIH/solr/tika/conf/schema.xml
/solr/solr-5.2.1/example/example-DIH/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml

Comment: Do I need to manually setup this file? I am using solr out of the box and installed myself from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Probably the analysing of your `cus_email_t` field is not correct. So take a look at the `schema.xml` and find out, if there is -for example- an valid tokenizer, that splits your term in order to extract the Mail-Address.

An other important point is to check, if the field definition is set to `indexed=true`:

`<field name="cus_email_t" type="..." indexed=true ... />`

Comment: Thanks for the answer; asked this above, do I manually need to copy and setup this file for each core I build?

Comment: Normally, every core has it's own `schema.xml`.     You also could use the anlays-page from the solr Admin interface. There you can see, how your field is analysed by solr and which tokenizer, filter, etc are applied to your term.

Comment: This seems the least documented part of setup. So I have taken a copy of schema.xml, and copied it into solr/core_name/conf Because I am using dynamic felds in my naming, I am assuming I don't need to add anything else to the setup, just stop and restart the server after altering the schema.xml file?

Comment: It is important to take a look at the `solrconfig.xml`, to find out, if and which `schema.xml` is used. >just stop and restart the server after altering the schema.xml file< depending on your changes in the `schema.xml` an restart AND an index-rebuild is needed. For example, if you set `indexed=true`, then you also need an index-rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions in the comments about schema.xml:
By default, solr 5.2.1 will generate a managed-schema for you. If you try to make changes to a schema.xml file while Solr is trying to manage if for you it will generate another managed-schema and overwrite any changes you make, as it is meant to be modified through a REST API.

If you want to manually change your schema in schema.xml you need to go into your yourcore/solrconfig.xml file and change the "class" attribute of the "schemaFactory" tag to "ClassicIndexSchemaFactory".

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

Now Solr will read your schema.xml file. There is a comment block above the tag that explains this.

Now you can make changes to how your fields are analyzed as mentioned in the previous answer.